# How can I plot factor and numbers?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
year  val
1966  1
1967  22
1968  55
1969  57
```

Here , year is a factor with levels

And val is numeric

How can I plot it with year in x-axis and val in y-axis?

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x="year",y="val"))+
geom_line()+
ggsave('test.png')
```

**Actual dataset**

```
df <- structure(list(year = structure(1:47, .Label = c("1936", "1947", 
    "1948", "1950", "1952", "1954", "1957", "1959", "1961", "1972", 
    "1973", "1975", "1979", "1980", "1981", "1982", "1983", "1984", 
    "1985", "1986", "1987", "1988", "1989", "1990", "1991", "1992", 
    "1993", "1994", "1995", "1996", "1997", "1998", "1999", "2000", 
    "2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", 
    "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013"), class = "factor"), val = c(1L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 43L, 
    146L, 108L, 68L, 200L, 414L, 367L, 977L, 1996L, 1768L, 1875L, 
    3235L, 1966L, 2244L, 3500L, 2479L, 3536L, 2062L, 1687L, 2563L, 
    2576L, 3884L, 3969L, 3101L, 2810L, 2941L, 4207L, 3353L, 2596L, 
    4485L, 1801L, 3286L)), .Names = c("year", "val"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -47L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: `plot(df$year,df$val)`... Use `xaxt="n"` and `axis(side=1,labels=levels(df$year))` to get the years themselves to print.

Comment: If you wanted to use ggplot, just put year and val in quotes, `x="year", y="val"` Should help. ( I have limited experience with ggplot, I could be wrong here.)

Comment: why are you using `aes_string` in this case? `ggplot(data=df)+
    geom_line(aes(x=year,y=val))` works fine, or use quotes as @HoneyDippedBadger says above.

Comment: I have put the actual dataset now, and I am getting a blank.

Comment: It looks like your column names are now `year` and `val`, but `Var1` and `Freq` -- simply renaming them (with `names(df) <- c("year", "val")`) should do the trick

Comment: Already did that. I am actually getting the black canvas and no line on it.

Comment: The problem is you have years as a factor, and geom_lines don't go between factors. Either use a different geom (geom_bar is good for factors), or convert your years to numeric with `df$year <- as.numeric(as.character(df$year))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: after having data in OP's question

Change year to numeric

```
df$year<-as.numeric(as.character(df$year))
```

Now, plot

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=year, y=val))+geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: I have added the full dataset.

Comment: Do you want to work with factors? change year to numeric